# Data not being inserted into table, but php file is loading. objective C

Tags: php, ios, mysql, objective-c

I am trying to create a group account that is tied to the user who is logged in my app. all the code is running right and it is connecting to the DB but for some reason it wont insert the new group into my DB table. Heres what I have so far. any help would be greatly appreciated. 
php file

```
        $con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass);
        mysql_select_db("$DB_Name");


            $email = $_GET['email'];
            $userid = $_GET['userid'];  
            $bname = $_GET['bname'];
            $bgenre = $_GET['bgenre'];
            $bio = $_GET['bio'];


        $sql = "insert into $DB_Table (bname, bgenre, bio, userid) values('$bname', '$bgenre','$bio','$userid')
        select userid from $DB_Table2 where email = '$email';
        $res = mysql_query($sql,$con);

        mysql_close($con);
        if($res) {
            echo"You created a band!";
        }else{
            echo"Band account wasn't created";
        }

?>
```

vc1.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface loginUserViewController : UIViewController


@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *email;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *password;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *login;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *registerBtn;


-(IBAction)loginUser:(id)sender;





@end
```

vc2.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "loginUserViewController.h"


@interface Home : UIViewController


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *username;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *Nav;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *logout;


-(IBAction)logout:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)bandHome:(id)sender;

@end
```

vc2.m

```
#import "Home.h"
#import "loginUserViewController.h"


@interface Home ()

@end

@implementation Home
@synthesize username, band1, band2, band3;

-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if(self){

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    loginUserViewController *object = [[loginUserViewController alloc]init];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i",[object.email.text intValue]];

    username.text = string;
}
```

vc3.m

```
#import "loginUserViewController.h"
#import "Home.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "createBandViewController.h"

@interface loginUserViewController ()


@end

@implementation loginUserViewController

@synthesize email, password;
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}
- (void)viewDidload
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{

    [self setEmail:nil];
    [self setPassword:nil];

    [super viewDidUnload];
}
-(IBAction)loginUser:(id)sender {
    if ([email.text isEqualToString:@""] || [password.text isEqualToString:@""])

    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"alert" message:@"Please Fill all the field" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }


    NSMutableString *strURL = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~team54/login2.php?email=%@&password=%@", email.text, password.text ];

    [strURL setString:[strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

    NSMutableString *strResult = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:dataURL  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   NSLog(@"logging in");

    if ([strResult isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Logged in!");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];

    }else
    {
        // invalid information
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"alert" message:@"Invalide Information" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        return;

    }
    email.text = @"";
    password.text = @"";

}
```

vc3.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface createBandViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *bname;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *bgenre;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *bio;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *createBand;

-(IBAction)addBand:(id)sender;

@end
```

Comment: Your PHP doesn't even look valid. Neither does the SQL in context.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run 2 queries at once. Separate them out. Also, stop using mysql_ functions as they've been deprecated, and removed as of PHP7. Migrate your functions to use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: so like this:  $sql = "insert into $DB_Table (bname, bgenre, bio, userid) values('$bname', '$bgenre','$bio','$res2')";
  $sql1 = "select userid from $DB_Table2 where email = '$email'";
  $res2 = mysqli_query($sql1,$con);
  $res = mysqli_query($sql,$con);

Comment: Yes, that may work better

Comment: Nope still not working.still trying out putting band wasnt created